# IE rendering problem of data

Tags: css

http://ratingscorner.com/product_rating.php?alias=Rashtreeya-Vidyalaya-College-of-Engineering-Mysore-Road-Bangalore&product=colleges

i have a page like the above .the page gets rendered properly in FF and other browsers. but in IE a small problem exits . IF you see the 1st box that is where the image and other features are displayed. the width of the box is differently shown in IE and FF. in IE the right hand side is getting cut off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the

```
table-layout:fixed;
```

from the inline style attribute of the table tag, it seems to render much better under IE7

Comment: okie will try it.You mean to say that width problem is solved if i remove the inline style ?

Comment: i tried it out dude. but the data still moves to right hand side .